# Simple way to add a legend in QGIS 3.8.2?

Tags: qgis-3, legend

I'm making a simple map using QGIS 3.8.2 and data from OSM.  The maps looks good, but I'd like to add a legend.  It seems like there used to be an "add new legend" button in older versions of QGIS, but I can find nothing like that in 3.8.2.  Is is still possible to add a legend without writing python code?

Addendum: Ok, after seeing ahmadhamb's answer I am very confused.  His screen and menus look very different than mine.  I am attaching a screenshot of what I have, with the opening screen in the background and the "About QGIS" screen in the foreground.  Where do I get the QGIS that ahmadhamb has???

[image]

Comment: @ahmadhanb answer refers to QGIS print composer. Open it by Project --> Layouts. If thats not what you are looking for, you can find the legend for your layers (once you added them) in the lower left corner within "layers"

Comment: Ah!  Okay, I see.  I opened my QGIS project, then used  Project --> New Print Layout to create an empty print layout.  Then I used Add Item --> Add Map to place my map on the print layout, and now I see the screen that ahmadhadb showed, including the Add Legend button.  Also, in the QGIS user guide online I find a section on "Laying out the maps" that explains this part of the software.  Thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add legend is still there in QGIS 3.8.3 that I have. Open QGIS print composer via Project --> Layouts. You can add it from the `Add item` from the main menu bar or click on `Add legend button` from the left side toolbox.

[image]